# for loop to iterate code and change variable's name

Tags: python, loops, variables, optimization

I want to optimize the following code by using loop so as to keep only one line and change the name of variables txyz where x, y, z change in range(1,3). Can someone help me figure it out?

```
        prob += (t111).sum() <= max_clients + 1
        prob += (t112).sum() <= max_clients + 1
        prob += (t113).sum() <= max_clients + 1
        prob += (t121).sum() <= max_clients + 1
        prob += (t122).sum() <= max_clients + 1
        prob += (t123).sum() <= max_clients + 1
        prob += (t131).sum() <= max_clients + 1
        prob += (t132).sum() <= max_clients + 1
        prob += (t133).sum() <= max_clients + 1
        prob += (t211).sum() <= max_clients + 1
        prob += (t212).sum() <= max_clients + 1
        prob += (t213).sum() <= max_clients + 1
        prob += (t221).sum() <= max_clients + 1
        prob += (t222).sum() <= max_clients + 1
        prob += (t223).sum() <= max_clients + 1
```

Comment: put all variables in an array, then iterate on it. the goal is not to implify THAT code, but the whole code, multiple variables representating different version of the same kind should be stored in an array; could you share more code so we see their definition ?

Comment: The reason this is difficult is because you are using a bunch of individual variables when you should be using a list or a dict. Avoiding this kind of code is on of the reasons why we have data structures.

Comment: Yes indeed. so there is no way to handle it by usine for x in range() for y in range() .. i guess i shoud better structure the variable as a tuple.

Comment: dont show code in comment, [edit] your post ;) You can't handle 1000 variables ^^ do you about lists ?

Comment: If you start to add digits to the names of your variables you are doing something wrong (in 99% of all cases).